# Debug Failure. False expression: parameter should have errors when reporting errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, build, eslint

this is my first time building a Next JS app with typescript and experiencing this error which is not helpful to me. "Debug Failure. False expression: parameter should have errors when reporting errors"

[image: This is the error message]

when I saw the errors I think this has something to do with node modules so I tried to delete and install the node modules, still the same error happening

*your text*[image: Still the same error]